# How to print order ref name in pos receipt odoo

Tags: odoo, pos

I want to add order ref name in receipt.Check my image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways i.e. by editing from front end, or by extending the template.

**Option1: From Front end**

1. Activating Developer Mode.
2. Then Technical
3. Then Reports.
4. Find your desire report and edit it.

**Option2: Extending The Template**

```
<template id="report_invoice_document_inherit321" inherit_id="external_id_of_template">
   <xpath expr="YOUR_XPATH_WHERE_YOU_WANT_YOUR_OUTPUT" position="after">
                
   </xpath>
</template>
```